# Ax 2012 version control not working

Tags: version-control, axapta, microsoft-dynamics

HI for some reason i am not able to add my project to version control, its showing option add to version control but when i click that there is no response, can any one tell me the reason and how it should be solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your workspace in Visual Studio (View -> Team Explorer). Ensure that you have correct workspace workspace used by AX (ex: `*MachineName*_AXWORKSPACE0`). Then check the state of VCS (make backup of all files and try with *Undo checkout*). Sometimes AOS needs to be restarted.

Comment: i also needed to clear app data and then aos restart in addition to above suggestion.